# Logical formula in Excel - Help needed

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need help with an excel formula. I am trying to achieve the following behaviour:

- the formula is in cell A
- in cell B we can have 3 possible values - Low, Medium or High

So if value of cell B is equal to Low then in the A cell the value is "Yes"
If the value in cell B is equal to Medium or High then the formula should check if cell C is populated and its content is different then "please fill in" or it is left "blank". If true then cell A is "Yes", if not, then it is "No".

If value of cell B is blank then the cell A is "No" as well.

Comment: Have you played around with `=IF(...)` ?

Comment: I have tried something like this =IF(UPPER(B1)="LOW", "Yes",IF(UPPER(C1)="please fill in", "No", "Yes")) but doesn't work :(

Comment: should be close. but it should be `LOWER(C1)` instead of `UPPER(C1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not great with formulas but this would do

```
=IF(LEN(B1)>0,IF(B1="low","Yes",IF(B1="medium",IF(C1<>"please fill in",IF(C1<>"","Yes","No"),"No"),IF(B1="high",IF(B1<>"please fill in",IF(LEN(C1)>0,"Yes","No"),"No"),"No"))),"No")
```

if you want a VBA function ( but requires you to enter the formula in each cell separately then stick this in a module and then use it in column A

```
Function CheckIt() As String
    Dim r As Long
    r = ActiveCell.Row
    If Range("B" & r) = "low" Then
        CheckIt = "Yes"
    Else
        If (Range("B" & r) = "medium" Or Range("B" & r) = "high") Then
            If ((Range("C" & r) <> "please fill in") And (Not IsEmpty(Range("C" & r)))) Then
                CheckIt = "Yes"
            Else
                CheckIt = "No"
            End If
        Else
            CheckIt = "No"
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Example

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question but once I enter the module, how do I use it. Not very good in excel :(

Comment: @largan you simply go into cell A1 and type `=CheckIt()` and hit Return/Enter

Comment: @largan you need to open VBE (visual basic editor ALT + F11 ) , right click project explorer and insert - module. Then copy-paste the Function code in there

Comment: Thanks I have manage to inser it and use it... but somehow the logic doesnt work. It stays on "NO" and doesnt change the value

Comment: Hmmm, thats weird... In fact it works, but only if I click on the field (A) and insert =CheckIt()... Then if I change the values in B or C it doesn't change. And if I go again to A and resubmit the =CheckIt() it then shoes the correct value

Comment: `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` general setting needs to be globally switched on

Comment: By globally you mean using the Formulas tab and then using the calculation options or other way ?

Comment: I tried switching putting the code in the VB, also tried to switch it in the excel (was already switched on) in the formula tab... but it didn't work. Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

The following formula replicates textually the logic you asked about

```
=IF(B1="Low","Yes",IF(OR(B1="Medium",B1="High"),IF(OR(ISBLANK(C1),C1<>"please fill in"),"Yes","No"),IF(ISBLANK(B1),"No","Undefined")))
```

Note that there is a case that you left out of your definition (which gives "Undefined"). This is probably not intended.

If "Undefined" is actually not intended, note also that you have only two possible outputs, so the condition can be replaced by a different test, with a single condition combining `AND`/`OR`s instead of nested `IF`s.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of IF, OR, ISBLANK and UPPER should solve your problem.

```
=IF(UPPER(B2)="LOW","Yes",IF(OR(UPPER(C2)="PLEASE FILL IN",ISBLANK(C2)),"Yes","No"))
```

[image: Example of formula]

Comment: +1 for much shorter formula than mine :P like I said im not great at building formulas